# SCREEN PHP detached mode with Arguments

Tags: php, gnu-screen

I had a simple php script, which i would like to start from the console in a detached mode with screen.

my problem is:

the program needs two arguments and the output of this script should be write in a specified file.

so how to do it like

```
screen -d -m php bl.php 3 2 > rob.dat
```

Please help me.

Comment: Why cant you start the screen, start the script, then detach the screen?

Comment: because the syntax is wrong.  the arguments arent passed with the > file.dat

Comment: @Karpie: like my post, the command wont work. in the php script, the echo want get into the file :-/

Comment: Can't you write the output to the log via php itself ?

Answer (score 1):

You may start screen first, execute the command and then detach it.

```
screen -S mySession
php b1.php 3 2 > rob.dat
[Strg]+A, d
```